# Download files in parallel using go-routines and channel causing resource leak?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have below code where I download `s3` files in parallel. But my intellij IDE complains that there is a resource leak on this line `defer close(chans[i])`.

```
func (s3client *S3Client) BatchDownloadFiles(bucket string, prefix string, suffix string) (res []Result, err error) {
    files, err := s3client.ListObjects(bucket, prefix, suffix)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    names := make([]Result, len(files))
    var chans []chan Result
    for i, key := range files {
        chans = append(chans, make(chan Result))
        // resource leak here?
        defer close(chans[i])

        go s3client.downloadZipFiles(bucket, key, chans[i])
    }

    for i, c := range chans {
        names[i] = <-c
        if names[i].Err != nil {
            err = names[i].Err
        }
    }

    return names, err
}
```

How can I fix this resource leak here? or if there is any better way like using one channel then any ideas will be welcome here.

Comment: What _exactly_ does the suggestion say, and which program is generating the message? Calling `close` there is not a leak, and actually does nothing in your code.

Comment: My Intellij IDE just say - `Possible resource leak, 'defer' is called in the 'for' loop` and no suggestion on how to fix it. @JimB

Comment: Calling `defer` in a for loop is often a mistake, but why are you calling it at all here?

Comment: I am pretty new to golang and I thought defer will close this at the end so prolly made a mistake I guess. I didn't realize it will cause resource leak there.

Comment: You have no reason to call `close` on the channel in this code. The possible "resource leak" stems from continually adding defers within a loop which won't actually be executed until the surrounding function returns.

Comment: What is the right way to fix this then? @JimB

Comment: you have no reason to call close here, just get rid of it.

Comment: apart from your question, why cant you use a single channel for all the downloads?

Comment: @JimB ok removed it.

Comment: @TheFool yeah I was reading about it on how to do it so I came up with that. If you can provide an example on how to do that with single channel then it will be of great help.